# How do I select elements within a #document to change the CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to remove the icon in svg tag in CSS i am trying to make height and width null:

```
<iframe style="box-sizing: border-box;" allowfullscreen="true" allowvr="true" frameborder="0" src="http://vizor.io/embed/bitra/gfx2" width="959.18" height="539.53875" id="_id_jfuzvdmpi">
  #document
    <html> 
       <body>
            <div class="overlay">
              <a><svg class="icon" viewBox="0 0 26 26"</a>
            </div>
       </body> 
    </html>
</iframe>
```

in css : icon{ width=26; height=26}

now i want to change the icon{width=null; height=null}

Answer (score 0):

`null` is not valid CSS but you can do `width: 0; height: 0`, or `display: none`.

Comment: Hi Ben West , i changed the values of width: 0; height: 0  to zero but how do i select the elements with in a #document

Comment: Oh, an iframe - sorry, I misunderstood your question.